# Change image from GitHub's repository when publishing link

Tags: image, github

Does anyone know how can I change the image on my GitHub's repository when I'm publishing its link? 
Currently, it's showing my profile image.

[image]

I've added the desired image to social preview in GitHub repository's settings but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: It usually takes time for the DNS servers to update, so maybe wait a day maximum.

Comment: Also make sure you're following the tip here: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/customizing-your-repositorys-social-media-preview that says: "Your image should be a PNG, JPG, or GIF file under 1 MB in size. For the best quality rendering, we recommend keeping the image at 640 by 320 pixels."